# Android : Icon not taking full bordered rectangle

Tags: android

DISCLAIMER : THESE ARE NOT MY APPS

My icon looks like the one on the left on Android 9.0+. On Android 6.0 however, it's just a circle. How do I make it look like the one on the right?

[image]

Comment: use [adaptive icon](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_adaptive)

Comment: Suggest reading over [Google Play icon design specifications](https://developer.android.com/google-play/resources/icon-design-specifications) - Check the Legacy mode section.

Comment: @Avinash This is app icon. Not ImageView.

Comment: Please check your mipmap folder each mipmap folder like mdpi,hdpi,xhdpi,xxhdpi,xxhdpi have two icons one for rounded and second for rounded corner.

Comment: In manifest use  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_rounded"

Comment: @Avinash That's exactly how it's setup. I'm already looking at Adaptive Icons as suggested by Mahonar Reddy

Answer (score 1):

When you insert image for icon in android asset studio in this select Legacy from 3 tab then Round icon generate option default tick Yes you make to it to No then you get your requirement then try to run.

see below ss.

[image]